# Reatogo (~ BartPE) SATA BSOD: Either 0x0000007B or 0x0000007E

Tags: windows, sata, bsod, bartpe

I'm trying to get [Reatogo's PE Builder](http://www.reatogo.de/REATOGO.htm) (a variant of [Bart's PE Builder](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/)) to work with SATA drives.

If I put the SATA driver in the `SCSIDriver` folder, then it boots fine on SATA drives, but it gives a BSOD with error `0x0000007E` on IDE drives.

If I do *not* integrate the SATA driver, then it boots fine on IDE drives, but it gives a BSOD with error `0x0000007B` on SATA drives.

I think I managed to get BartPE to work fine on both once, but I don't remember how... does anyone have any solution?

("Make a separate disc for each" or "Change your AHCI BIOS settings" are **not** solutions!)